# Optimizing SPOJ edit distance solution

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded, edit-distance

I was doing a standard problem of DP (dynamic programming) on SPOJ  [Edit Distance](http://www.spoj.com/problems/EDIST/) using Python.

```
t = raw_input()  

for i in range(int(t)):    
   a,b = raw_input(),raw_input()

   r = len(a)
   c = len(b)
   x = [[0]*(c+1) for j in range(r+1)]

   for j in range(c+1):
       x[0][j] = j

   for j in range(r+1):
       x[j][0] = j

   for j in range(1,r+1):
       for k in range(1,c+1):
           if(b[k-1]!=a[j-1]):
              x[j][k] = min(x[j-1][k-1]+1,x[j-1][k]+1,x[j][k-1]+1)
           else:
              x[j][k] = min(x[j-1][k-1],x[j-1][k]+1,x[j][k-1]+1) 

   print x[r][c]
```

The solution I have proposed is giving T.L.E (Time Limit Exceeded) even though I am using D.P. Is there any way to optimize it further in terms of time complexity or with respect to any feature of Python 2.7 such as input and output?

Comment: you can group these things into descriptive functions, moving some of the arguments into variables would help because they would give a hint to the intent of them

Comment: this works pretty quickly for me; are you testing it on very long strings?

Comment: @Stuart the max size of strings are 2000 characters....... I don't think we can improve the solution algorithmically but can we improve it with respect to some feature of python like fast input/output,etc..

Comment: ah. because they run it on the slow cluster and presumably use long strings. You could look in to improving the algorithm with something like `collections.deque` - I doubt the input/output methods will make much difference. But I see no one has solved this problem with python yet.

Comment: @stuart you can go to the best solutions for this problem and see that there are two python solutions..... how can we use **collections.deque** ????

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right. I noted with your solution that in each iteration you are only accessing a certain part of `x`, and that this could be done by manipulating a deque instead of a list of lists, and might be faster. I doubt it would bring the speed improvement you need though. The fastest solution is 2.65s which must be using a much better algorithm, probably with more use of special data types and libraries.

Comment: Checking the forums, [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) was available on spoj in the past but has now been disabled. This may make it hard to achieve times using Python that were possible up until last year.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved that problem in java and c++ ([2nd and 3th places](http://www.spoj.com/ranks/EDIST/) in best solutions category :) so I can compare the local and the remote execution time in order to see - how much faster should be your solution in order to pass.

So, the local execution time of my java solution is 78 ms for the [such testcase](http://pastebin.com/5Q9h5dRK) (10 pairs x 2000 chars), the robot's time is 500 ms, so my PC is ~6.5 times faster. Then the following python DP solution takes 3.6 seconds on my PC so, it would take ~23.5 seconds on the remote PC. So if the remote time limit 15 seconds, the following solution **must be minimum ~ 1.56 times faster** in order to pass. Ufff....

```
import time

try:
    # just to see the Python 2.5 + psyco speed - 17 times faster than Python 2.7 !!!
    import psyco
    psyco.full()
except:
    pass

def editDistance(s1, s2):
    if s1 == s2: return 0 
    if not len(s1):
       return len(s2)
    if not len(s2):
       return len(s1)
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1
    r1 = range(len(s2) + 1)
    r2 = [0] * len(r1)
    i = 0
    for c1 in s1:
        r2[0] = i + 1
        j = 0
        for c2 in s2:
            if c1 == c2:
                r2[j+1] = r1[j]
            else:
                a1 = r2[j]
                a2 = r1[j]
                a3 = r1[j+1]
                if a1 > a2:
                    if a2 > a3:
                        r2[j+1] = 1 + a3
                    else:
                        r2[j+1] = 1 + a2
                else:
                    if a1 > a3:
                        r2[j+1] = 1 + a3
                    else:
                        r2[j+1] = 1 + a1
            j += 1
        aux = r1; r1 = r2; r2 = aux
        i += 1
    return r1[-1] 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    st = time.time()
    t = raw_input()  
    for i in range(int(t)):    
        a, b = raw_input(), raw_input()
        print editDistance(a, b)
    #print "Time (s): ", time.time()-st
```

What I can say - It's very very hard or may be impossible to pass that puzzle using Python and DP approach (using java or c++ - peace of cake). Wait, wait - ask you - what about that two guys [that passed using python](http://www.spoj.com/ranks/EDIST/lang=PYTH%202.7)? Ok, the answer is easy - they use something different. What's exactly? Something that [I've used for java solution](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8941/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/util/editdistance/MyersBitParallelEditDistance.java) I think. That stuff just blows away the competitors....

Comment: Thanks @cat_baxter i am not much familiar with java but i will try and look into the algo part of that java solution and try to implement it in python if possible ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much to improve in terms of performance. However, you could make the code a whole lot more self-descriptive, e.g. using better variable names, and moving the actual calculation into a function that can be called with different inputs. Here's my try:

```
def min_edit_distance(word1, word2, subst=1):
    len1, len2 = len(word1), len(word2)
    med = [[0] * (len2 + 1) for j in range(len1 + 1)]
    for j in xrange(len1 + 1):
        for k in xrange(len2 + 1):
            if min(j, k) == 0:
                med[j][k] = max(j, k) # initialization
            else:
                diag = 0 if word1[j-1] == word2[k-1] else subst
                med[j][k] = min(med[j-1][k-1] + diag, # substite or keep
                                med[j-1][k  ] + 1,    # insert
                                med[j  ][k-1] + 1)    # delete
    return med[len1][len2]
```

Main points:

- move the actual calculation into a function, for reusability
- use more descriptive names instead of one-letter variables
- different calculations of minimum edit distance use different costs for substitutions -- sometimes `1`, sometimes `2` -- so this could be a parameter
- unless I'm mistaken the `min` in your `else` is not necessary; `x[j-1][k-1]` will always be the best
- the two initialization loops can be incorporated into the main double-loop. (Clearly this is a question of taste. Initialization loops are more typical for DP, while this variant is closer to the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Definition).)